# how to use useNavigate in class component....where the react-router-dom is 6 version

Tags: reactjs

now for my class component Dashboard i used like this to have access to location and navigate....
location is working fine as its getting displayed in the props....but how can i pass navigate.....its not throwing any errors when im using this.props.navigate....but its supposed to navigate to ('/login') page....and its not doing that......how do i have access to navigate

```
     function DashboardWrapper(props) {

    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return <Dashboard {...props} navigate={navigate}  location={location} />;

   }
  export default withStyles(appStyle)(DashboardWrapper);
```